# Optimization Disables Insertion of Address-Size Override Prefix

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, warnings

When compiling this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

void foo(void)
{
        *(uint16_t *) (0xb8000) = 0xf61;
}
```

with

```
gcc test.c -c -m16 -O1
```

I get the following warning:

```
/tmp/ccyziKm4.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccyziKm4.s:9: Warning: 753664 shortened to 32768
```

And when I drop the `-O1` switch, I get none and gcc uses the `0x67` prefix to switch address size as expected (`-m16` basically emits prefixed 32-bit code):

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   66 55                   push   %ebp
   2:   66 89 e5                mov    %esp,%ebp
   5:   66 b8 00 80 0b 00       mov    $0xb8000,%eax
   b:   67 c7 00 61 0f          movw   $0xf61,(%eax)
  10:   90                      nop
  11:   66 5d                   pop    %ebp
  13:   66 c3                   retl
```

So, obviously this has something to do with the optimization switch `-O1`. The gcc man page describes all the options it sets and I wrote a script to single out every one of them and pass them to gcc, but it doesn't really work. Now, gcc does not show the warning at all, even with the whole bunch of them.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Comment: what happens if you use `0xb8000UL`?

Comment: @Lashane No change.

Comment: Just for completeness, the instruction that _GCC_ tried to generate with `-O1` was `movw    $3937, 753664`

Comment: I have seen issues like this before, and to this day I consider the Bin utils `.code16gcc` an unstable bastardization. I consider this a deficiency in GAS. Personally I think if the `.code16gcc` directive is present and the memory operand is displacement only and the displacement exceeds 0xffff then it should encode the instruction with the `addr32` prefix and effectively convert this case to `addr32 movw $3937, 753664`

Comment: You might get the desired effect with `__asm__ __volatile__ ("addr32 movw %[val], %[mem]" : [mem]"=m"(*(uint16_t *)0xb8000) : [val]"ri"(0xf61));` . You could put this in a function wrapper (with the `always_inline` attribute) and convert it for the general case. In the case of memory mapped device at 0xb8000 you'd want to make it `volatile`

Comment: The problem here though the code you want, `movw $0xf61,0xb8000` with 32-bit addressing wouldn't normally work in 16-bit code. In 16-bit mode, both 16-bit protected mode and real mode, the segment limits are all set to 64k (or less). The offset 0xb8000 is well beyond this 64k limit, so it'll generate a general protection fault. You can get around this by loading DS with a 32-bit selector (under 32-bit protected mode or "unreal" mode), but if you're doing that you might as well doing everything in 32-bit protected mode and not have to deal with all this nonsense.

Comment: I'm assuming if he is running this code that he is knowingly doing so in an unreal mode. But that may be a false assumption. Personally if I wanted to write 16-bit real mode code with C I'd switch to Open Watcom C.

Comment: @RossRidge I am running in Unreal Mode as MichaelPetch said. The thing is that there is a lot of information I want to gather, which is provided by BIOS routines such as a memory map, so I need to stick to Real Mode for a while. But Unreal Mode does pretty well so far.

Comment: Side note: In the case of 16-bit immediates you run into an [LCP stall](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-performance-bottleneck-analyzer/topic/328256) so the inline assembly I wrote imposes a new problem. One way around that is to change `[val]"ri"(0xf61)` to `[val]"r"(0xf61)` so that a 16-bit immediate can't be encoded in the template. If this were bytes and dwords then usage of `"ri"` would make sense.

Comment: You can't invoke BIOS routines directly from C code, you need to use assembly, inline or not, so you might as well grab all the information you need in plain 16-bit real mode assembly and then switch to 32-bit protected mode. The `.code16gcc` hack is meant to trick GCC into generating code it's not designed to support, and your attempt to use a 32-bit offset goes beyond even what `.code16gcc` is meant to support.

Comment: @MichaelPetch There will a much bigger "stall" when the GPF occurs and his unreal mode handler reloads DS with the 32-bit selector after some BIOS routine or interrupt reloaded it with a real-mode segment. (Assuming he's using that style of unreal mode implementation, otherwise it'll just crash.) In any case I don't think performance of this code actually matters.

Comment: Sure, I don't know how he handles unreal mode. But yes, best way to do it (in the case you might have a BIOS that flips to protected mode for any BIOS or interrupt call that has the effect of undoing unreal mode) is on the fly. Chain the GPF handler, Check the ISR (bit 5) to distinguish between a GPF and an IRQ. If IRQ call the original interrupt routine, If not then assume you need to flip into unreal mode and then return from the interrupt.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The BIOS doesn't need to flip into protected mode, it just needs to do `push ds` `pop ds` to reset the limit back to 64k.

Comment: You are incorrect there @RossRidge. Changing the value of a segment register (in real mode) doesn't alter the limit, but it does alter the base in the hidden registers / descriptor cache). So if you had a GDT entry where you specified a base that wasn't normal flipped into real mode the first time you attempt to alter that segment register the base will be set (but the limit would remain)

Comment: @RossRidge If you can believe the bochs implementation I am running, this is not true. After the Unreal Mode switch I zero out all segment registers and the limit is preserved. Only the base address changes.

Comment: @RossRidge All I am showing you is an MCVE to reproduce the problem. The real code is more complicated and it is *so* much more readable in C. gcc doesn't support real 16-bit code, true, but it is only marginally larger than the alternate assembly code, if at all, let alone faster: gcc unfortunately is better than me at producing efficient, non-trivial assembly, I've noticed. I did implement it all in assembly but switched to C for those very reasons. I was especially encouraged by Linux, which has undergone the same change.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Hmm... I stand corrected. I always thought loading segment registers in real mode affected entire selector cache state, base, limit and all the type and access bits.

Comment: On a completely other note, I tossed together some Openwatcom code that acts as a [16-bit bootloader](https://www.reddit.com/r/osdev/comments/68v6kp/seegol_a_16bit_open_source_operating_system_for/dhoi3td/?st=j2uvvx29&sh=09dceda2) for a Reddit post the other day. Not particularly useful, but an example nonetheless. I still work on some embedded 16-bit systems with variants of the 80186 processors so Openwatcom is still something I use for larger 16-bit projects.

Comment: @RossRidge : No problem. So many nuances with the x86 processors it often hard to keep them all straight. But yea, the access bits and limit remain untouched but the base will get set when the segment register is changed.

Comment: @Downvoter Yah, and all I'm explaining is why you're doing isn't as "efficient" you were hoping. You've pushed fragile hack to its breaking point, which shouldn't be a surprise. You shouldn't look to Linux for encouragement, you should see it as a special case that limits what you can do. If you run into other problems or future versions of GCC or binutils change or break something about `.code16gcc` it's only likely to be fixed if it causes problems in Linux. So don't take your inspiration from Linux, but mindlessly copy it and don't do anything it doesn't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that it is bug in gcc, but I see some logic behind this behavior:

GCC without optimization produces quite straightforward code with 2 instructions (I prefer intel syntax):

```
mov eax, 0xb8000 # move value 0xb8000 to eax
movw [eax], 0xf61 # move value 0xf61 to address stored in eax
```

Binary view:

```
66 b8 00 80 0b 00
   ^ operation: move 16 bit value to 16 register ax
^ size override prefix to indicate that 32 bit data is used instead of 16 bit, so eax should be used instead of ax

66 c7 00 61 0f
   ^ operation: move 16 bit value to 16 address in ax
^ size override prefix
```

GCC with optimization tries to optimize, so it generates following code:

```
movw [0xb8000], 0xf61 # mov value 0xf61 directly to 32 bit address 0xb8000 without any intermediate registers
```

Binary view:

```
66 c7 05 00 80 0b 00 61 0f
   ^ operation: move 16 bit value to 16 bit address
^ size override prefix
```

So, 32 bit op codes are actually the same opcodes as 16 bit, but with [66/67 prefix](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0240_prefix.htm).

And here is problem:

- operation `movw [REGISTER], 0xf61` is legal and officially supported in both 16/32 modes
- operation `movw [0xb8000], 0xf61` is legal, but values > 16 bit (0xffff) are not officially supported in 16 real mode, in 32 protected - they are officially supported

This is why compiler emits warning and truncates value 0xb8000 to 0x8000 to generate legal and officially supported instruction.

Note: I believe that gcc should emit warning in first case too, as it does not work as you'd expected in 16 bit:

1. In real mode such instruction allowed, but `eax` cannot exceed `0xffff` (effectively it does not use `eax` but only `ax` part).
2. in protected/unreal mode such instruction allowed and full `eax` will be used.

---

I don't know why gcc allows you to use `m16` flag, while not supporting 16 bit code generation and real mode memory models properly. I suggest you to switch to something else. 20 years ago watcom was very cool.

If you're in unreal mode, it automatically means that you can and should use m32 instructions.

Comment: `mov [0xb8000], 0xf61` with an address override prefix is allowable and will work with offsets > 0xffff if the machine is in what has become known as [Unreal Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode). In AT&T syntax you can place the keyword `addr32` in front of the instruction. In _NASM_ syntax you can place the `a32` keyword in front of the instruction.

Comment: On a 386-processor memory operands with 32-bit memory operands is permissible even in real mode. There is an operand and address override that can be placed on the instructions. It won't run on a real 8086/80186/80286 but the instructions are valid on a 386+.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm putting some updates to address your comments

Comment: This is difficult to explain. But Unreal mode is actually real mode. The only real difference is that you can address the entire 4gb of address space and the segments aren't limited to 64k. All the instructions (whether in unreal mode or real mode are decoded in the same way). `a32 movw [0xb8000], 0xf61` is a legal instruction in regular real mode on a 386+. The problem is that although legal in regular real mode it will cause a general protection fault because the address is >0xFFFF. In Unreal mode it won't fault because the entire address space is addressable.

Comment: The 32-bit encodings in real mode that work on 386+ won't work properly if run on a pre-386 processor. This is one of the biggest drawbacks of using GCC's 16-bit code generation.

Comment: @MichaelPetch right, this is what I'm saying too, and this is what gcc warns us about

Comment: Yoiur statement in your answer _operation movw [0xb8000], 0xf61 is impossible in 16 bit real mode at all, it is possible in 32 bit real/protected/unreal modes_ . is encodable with the 32-bit address operand prefix. It is a **legal instruction** in real or unreal mode, In real mode it will fault the processor (despite being a legal instruction) because 0xb8000 > 0xffff. In unreal mode the processor won't fault because 0xb8000 is <0xffffffff

Comment: I'm not sure you know this but you can encode this  (with address and operand override) and it will run properly in regular real mode on a 386: `mov eax, 0x1000` `mov dword [43+eax], 0xffffeeee`. You can use all the 386 addressing modes in real mode on a 386. You aren't just limited to _BX_, _BP_, _SI_, and _DI_. In regular real mode on a 386 - as long as the address that is computed fits between 0x0000 and 0xffff it will work. If you want to address an offset with these instructions above 0xffff you need to be in unreal mode.

Comment: Anywhere I said `< 0xffff` or `< 0xffffffff` I meant `<=`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I see what you mean, I've updated wording.